# Mixing Title and Tags form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I will ask my question based on stackoverflow "new question" page, because it is easier to explain.

We have 2 form fields title and tags in that page. What if we want to merge these to field. So if user types any word which starts with # sign we will recognize it as a tag and we will try to auto complete that, but if user keeps writing other words without # sign we know that these words are now part of the title itself.

User will type #ja and we will suggest java and javascript tags, then user select one of them, and he will keep writing but since he did not write # anymore we know that these words are now part of the questions title.

So what do I need to create this type of mixed field using javascript and html?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be a good start - easy to create a plugin that you require.

It maybe possible even with existing autocomplete plugins like

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ or one that goes with jQuery UI, but it has to be modified. First of all, delimiter must be a space instead of usual comma. Second, it would be good to modify plugin further so that it'll do ajax request only if the first character of the word is '#'. That way there won't be too much requests. And plugin will be able to to remove '#' from the call.

On the server side if we still have '#' in get/post request, remove it and proceed to do DB select. Then return data either with '#' prepending or without it so that javascript on callback would be able to add it if needed.

Not sure how plugins listed above handle tag replacement if we picked one from autocomplete, but i believe it won't be an issue. Probably if you'll go with bassistance plugin you'd have to replace delimiter that follows autocompleted tag (it inserts comma).